# why does editing an image with Lockbits still take 7 secs?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, drawing

### My Application

I am writing an application that needs to convert RGB to grayscale images.
The conversion works but converting an image of 3648 * 2736 pixel takes round about 7 secs.
I know that set and getpixel take some time.
But I think that it shouldn't take so long if you are using Lockbits even though the image is not small. (please correct me if that is wrong).
Maybe I just did a fatal mistake within my code.

### The code

```
public static long ConvertToGrayScaleV2(Bitmap imageColor, bool useHDTVConversion)
        {
            Stopwatch stpw = new Stopwatch();
            stpw.Start();
            System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData imageColorData = imageColor.LockBits(new Rectangle(new Point(0, 0), imageColor.Size),
                System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, imageColor.PixelFormat);

            IntPtr PtrColor = imageColorData.Scan0;
            int strideColor = imageColorData.Stride;
            byte[] byteImageColor = new byte[Math.Abs(strideColor) * imageColor.Height];
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(PtrColor, byteImageColor, 0, Math.Abs(strideColor) * imageColor.Height);

            int bytesPerPixel = getBytesPerPixel(imageColor);
            byte value;
            if (bytesPerPixel == -1)
                throw new Exception("Can't get bytes per pixel because it is not defined for this image format.");
            for (int x = 0, position; x < imageColor.Width * imageColor.Height; x++)
            {
                position = x * bytesPerPixel;
                if (useHDTVConversion)
                {
                    value = (byte)(byteImageColor[position] * 0.0722 + byteImageColor[position + 1] * 0.7152 + byteImageColor[position + 2] * 0.2126);                    
                }
                else
                {
                    value = (byte)(byteImageColor[position] * 0.114 + byteImageColor[position + 1] * 0.587 + byteImageColor[position + 2] * 0.299);
                }
                byteImageColor[position] = value;
                byteImageColor[position+1] = value;
                byteImageColor[position+2] = value;

            }

            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(byteImageColor, 0, PtrColor, Math.Abs(strideColor) * imageColor.Height);
            imageColor.UnlockBits(imageColorData);
            stpw.Stop();
            return stpw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        }

        public static int getBytesPerPixel(Image img)
        {
            switch (img.PixelFormat)
            {
                case System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format16bppArgb1555:    return 2;
                case System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format16bppGrayScale:   return 2;
                case System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format16bppRgb555: return 2;
                case System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format16bppRgb565: return 2;
                case System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed: return 1;
                case System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb: return 3;
                case System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb: return 4;
                case System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb: return 4;
                case System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb: return 4;
                case System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format48bppRgb: return 6;
                case System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format4bppIndexed: return 1;
                case System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format64bppArgb: return 8;
                case System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format64bppPArgb: return 8;
                case System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed: return 1;
                default: return -1;
            }

        }
```

Comment: Have you moved the Stopwatch start/stop points to figure out which part of the function is slow: LockBits, the marshaled copies, the loop itself? (Also, keep in mind that while you are getting the bytesPerPixel from the image format, the formula in your loop assumes 23- or 32-bit BGR-ordered pixels.)

Comment: I'm surprised it takes so long, too. I'd have guessed <2s. Profile the code (e.g. by stopping the debugger 10 times to see where it stops most often).

Comment: So i checked the code for the part that consumes most of the time. Till the loop it needs 27 msec. the loop takes 6007 msec and the last parts take 19 msec.

Comment: technically, I think you *could* parallelize the bits of the loop if it helped. Does it run just as slow in 'release' than 'debug' mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're converting to greyscale, try using a ColorMatrix transformation instead.
from: https://web.archive.org/web/20141230145627/http://bobpowell.net/grayscale.aspx

```
   Image img = Image.FromFile(dlg.FileName);
        Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(img.Width,img.Height);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bm); 

  

        
        ColorMatrix cm = new ColorMatrix(new float[][]{   new float[]{0.5f,0.5f,0.5f,0,0},
                                  new float[]{0.5f,0.5f,0.5f,0,0},
                                  new float[]{0.5f,0.5f,0.5f,0,0},
                                  new float[]{0,0,0,1,0,0},
                                  new float[]{0,0,0,0,1,0},
                                  new float[]{0,0,0,0,0,1}}); 

        

        /* 

        //Gilles Khouzams colour corrected grayscale shear
        ColorMatrix cm = new ColorMatrix(new float[][]{   new float[]{0.3f,0.3f,0.3f,0,0},
                                  new float[]{0.59f,0.59f,0.59f,0,0},
                                  new float[]{0.11f,0.11f,0.11f,0,0},
                                  new float[]{0,0,0,1,0,0},
                                  new float[]{0,0,0,0,1,0},
                                  new float[]{0,0,0,0,0,1}}); 

        */ 


        ImageAttributes ia = new ImageAttributes();
        ia.SetColorMatrix(cm);
        g.DrawImage(img,new Rectangle(0,0,img.Width,img.Height),0,0,img.Width,img.Height,GraphicsUnit.Pixel,ia);
        g.Dispose();
```

Comment: I read something about it but I still wonder why this code takes so long.

Comment: Ok now it takes 1275 msec. It is much faster but i am still confused thx.

Comment: Yeah - I also find it hard soemtimes to stop trying to figure out why something is slow even when I have a faster workaround.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is old, but a few possible valuable points:

The `imageColor.Width * imageColor.Height` is an expensive operation that you are running nearly 10 million times (3648 * 2736) more than you need to.

- The `for` loop is recalculating that **every single iteration**
- Not only that, but the CLR has to navigate to the Bitmap object's `Width` and `Height` properties **each** of those 10 million times, too. This is 30 million more operations than you need every time you try to run this on your bitmap.

Change:

```
for (int x = 0, position; x < imageColor.Width * imageColor.Height; x++)
{
    ...
}
```

To:

```
var heightWidth = imageColor.Width * imageColor.Height;
for (int x = 0, position; x < heightWidth; x++)
{
    ...
}
```

If you cache all the potential results of the three various operations (R, G, B, with 255 possible values) and use a lookup to the new values instead of calculating the new value 10 million times you'll also see a huge performance increase.

Here is the full, very fast code (much faster than a ColorMatrix). Notice I have moved all possible pre-calculated values into local variables and within the loop there absolutely minimal work involved.

```
                var lookupR = new byte[256];
                var lookupG = new byte[256];
                var lookupB = new byte[256];
                var rVal = hdtv ? 0.114 : 0.0722;
                var gVal = hdtv ? 0.587 : 0.7152;
                var bVal = hdtv ? 0.299 : 0.2126;
                for (var originalValue = 0; originalValue < 256; originalValue++)
                {
                    var r = (byte)(originalValue * rVal);
                    var g = (byte)(originalValue * gVal);
                    var b = (byte)(originalValue * bVal);
                    // Just in case...
                    if (r > 255) r = 255;
                    if (g > 255) g = 255;
                    if (b > 255) b = 255;
                    lookupR[originalValue] = r;
                    lookupG[originalValue] = g;
                    lookupB[originalValue] = b;
                }
                unsafe
                {
                    var pointer = (byte*)(void*)bitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, bitmap.PixelFormat);
                    var bytesPerPixel = getBytesPerPixel(bitmap);
                    var heightWidth = bitmap.Width * bitmap.Height;
                    for (var y = 0; y < heightWidth; ++y)
                    {
                        var value = (byte) (lookupR[pointer[0]] + lookupG[pointer[1]] + lookupB[pointer[2]]);
                        pointer[0] = value;
                        pointer[1] = value;
                        pointer[2] = value;
                        pointer += bytesPerPixel;
                    }
                    bitmap.UnlockBits();
                }
                break;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ^^ unfortunately this project is on another pc i am barely using

Answer (score 3):

I ran across a similar performance issue where I need to iterate over an array of bitmap data.  I found that there is a significant performance hit referencing the width or height properties of the bitmap within or as the bounds for the loop like you are doing with imagecolor.width and .height.   By simply declaring an integer outside the loop and caching the bitmap height and width there in advance, I cut my loop time in half.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that the marshalling and copying is taking a large chunk of the time.
This [link](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-convert-a-color-image-to-grayscale) describes 3 methods for greyscaling an image.